# Apache showing the default page after reinstall

Tags: centos, apache-http-server

I have just reinstalled `Apache` on my `Centos 6` VPS for tests and I'm not able to see the previous website.
I installed Nginx just for test but after the

```
yum erase nginx
```

and

```
yum install httpd
```

Apache show me just the default page, How can I solve this?
My site files are in `/var/www/html/` as usual

Comment: By uninstall Apache do you mean you removed everything? Did you restore your site files from backup?

Comment: I just stop `httpd` service and the `yum erase httpd`. I dind't used any backup just because all the files was in the /var/www/html folder. The onli solution I found is reimage the vps but then I shoul re-install everything

Comment: Have you checked to see if the files are actually there? Is this a live site you can link us to so we can have a look? EDIT: Sorry not trying to state the obvious. Just trying to find a starting point to find a problem.

Comment: Done, I reinstalled all the php support and restart also apache and now it works!

Comment: Good stuff :) was just going to make sure your DocuementRoot was also correct, but obviously it is. Have fun.